# Hadoop calculation depending on maximum value

Tags: hadoop, max

I have a question.

I want to make a mapping on a big data set and the mapping process depends on the maximum value.

For example

```
Input:
(key)  (value)    
--------------
key1   1
key2   2
key3   5
key4   6
key5   9
```

My calculation depends on the maximum value of these values, to map each point.
I want to divide these values into groups depending on the maximum number in the values.

For example, the maximum number in the previous input is 9 and I want to map them into 3 groups. I will use the new key as: `(int) value/(Max/3)`.

```
output(of mapping)
(new key)  (new Value)    
----------------------
0          key1
0          key2
1          key3
1          key4
2          key5
```

And I have the following mapper:

```
protected void map(Object key, InWritable value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int MaximumValue=???;
    int newKey = (int)value/(MaximumValue/3);
    context.write(newKey,Key);
}
```

But, how to calculate the maximum key, before iterating all the records?

Comment: You cannot, you need to do that part in the reduce function.
In the reducer when all the mapper values comes together, there only you can find the max key.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh, but you mean i should two chained jobs?. The first one will find the maximum value, and the second job will do the grouping?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.
Can you tell me what this line is doing **(int) value/(Max/3)**.
Because I think this line is not going to help you to create 3 groups.

Comment: I changed MAX to MaximumValue, the main idea is to bucketize the values into 3 groups so i need to find the bucket number of each value

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

**Note**: I am talking w.r.t Hadoop 1.2.1. You might have to make some modifications for newer API.

In your driver, read the `inputpath` and parse it and find the max value.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            fs.open(inpath)));
    String line = "";
    line = br.readLine();
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    try {
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.trim().length() == 0 || line.trim().equals("")) {
                line = br.readLine();
                continue;
            }
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            int val = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            if (val > max)
                max = val;
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Set it in your Configuration.

```
conf.setInt("max_val", max);
```

And read it in your mapper, by overriding the `configure()` method. For newer API, I think you have to override `setup()` method.

```
@Override
public void configure(JobConf conf) {
    max = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("max_val"));
}
```

Comment: This will not work, because as your suggested algorithm, the key of previous records should be changed(i.e) if maximum value was 9 until some points changed to 21, that means i should change the key of previous record instead the previous output to(0 key1,0 key2,0 key3,0 key4,1 key5)which cannot be done.

Comment: I didn't understand your above comment ^

Comment: sorry, i miss understand your solution,i just understand it, you mean detecting the maximumvalue from driver?. but this solution is also a time consuming in case i have a very long records.I prefer to use chained jobs instead.